# GeoAlchemy2 store point and query results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy

The documentation on GeoAlchemy2 doesn't seem fully featured (as compared to the pervious version).

I have a model:

```
class AddressCode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address_codes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(Unicode(34))
    geometry = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

And I want to store lat/long data, which I tried to save in the above model, example

```
"51.42553,-0.666085"
```

Which gives me the error:

```
"Parse error at position 9 within Geometry (the "," char")
```

Anyone able to shed some light on where I am going wrong here?

Also on the subject, how would I peform a query to say..

Show nearest 20 users:

```
class AddressCode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address_codes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(34))
    geometry = Column(Geometry('POINT'))
```

Something like?

```
geom_var = "51.42553,-0.666085"
Session.query(User).filter(func.ST_DWithin, 20, geom_var).all()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In both GeoAlchemy and GeoAlchemy2 you need to specify the geometries in the well-known text format called [WKT or Well-known text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), or the Well-known binary format. For a point the syntax is `'POINT(X Y)'`, thus `'POINT(-0.666085 51.42553)'` notice that the longitude comes first, then latitude.

The [shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) module contains useful functions for handling geometries outside relational databases, along with easy conversions between Python geometry classes and WKT, WKB formats.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

this region table is defined as:

```
regionTable = Table('region', metadata,
                Column('region_id', Integer, Sequence('region_region_id_seq'), primary_key=True),
                Column('type_cd', String(30)),
                Column('region_nm', String(255)),
                Column('geo_loc', Geography )
                )
```

how to query it:

(give me all regions within 50 miles of my current location..)

```
sqlstring = select([regionTable],
    func.ST_DWithin(
      regionTable.c.geo_loc,
      'POINT(-74.78886216922375 40.32829276931833)', 
      1609*50 ) )

result = connection.execute(sqlstring)

for row in result:
   print "region name:", row['region_nm']
```